# Regex multiline replacement failing to strip anything

Tags: regex, perl

I have a large text file with the following example of text in it. There are many "CHARTS" blocks, probably 200+ in total.

```
CHARTS
  Color=14671839
  Layer=7
  [0] Font=MS SAN SERIF,10,0,F,F,
'''other lines'''
  [28]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,


CHARTS
 Color=14671839
  Layer=4
  [0] Font=MS SAN SERIF,10,0,F,F,
...other lines...
  [28]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
```

I am trying to strip all blocks where "Layer=7" meaning the above text would end up as

```
CHARTS
 Color=14671839

  Layer=4
  [0] Font=MS SAN SERIF,10,0,F,F,
...other lines...
  [28]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
```

I have used the following:

```
$contents =~ s/CHARTS(?s)Layer\=7(?s).*?\[28\]\=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,//g;
```

I am not getting any errors BUT nothing is being stripped.

I have spent the last hour playing around with it but am getting nowhere. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Many thanks

Comment: The `CHARTS` are always separated by an empty line and no other empty lines in the file? you want include an empty line before the `Layer=4`?

Comment: if the `CHARTS` are separated by empty line (and no other empty lines are in the file) the: `perl -00 -nlE '$/="\n\n";say unless /Layer=7\b/' < file` could do the job...

Comment: Are you trying to strip out a complete block which has a `Layer=7` in it? Or you wanna strip out lines starting from `Layer=7` up to `Layer=[Any digits except 7]?`

Comment: There are other empty lines in the file unfortunately. This is a file created by a system over which I have no control so I cannot remove them.

Yes, I am looking to remove the entire "Layer=7" block and NOT just the line in which it sits.

Comment: Is there a reason the replace string I am currently using is not working?

Comment: Yes, your regex doesn't even match a single byte because at the first place it can't match a block with beginning of `CHARTSLayer=7` implemented in your regex.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to ignore all `CHARTS` blocks which have a `Layer` attribute assigned to something other than `7` from being removed:

```
$contents =~ s/CHARTS\R*(^(?!CHARTS) *+(?(?=Layer=(?:7\d+|[^7]))(*SKIP)(*F)|.*)\R)*//gm;
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/QQYKuk)

Comment: Just because you've heard of regex conditional expressions and backtrack control verbs, you don't have to use them in every application. This is a horribly arcane mishmash to achieve such a simple thing.

Comment: Sorry but I don't care about such comments which try to degrade a valid answer. It's not a good way to promote yours.

Comment: It's "valid" only in the sense that it works. And you care so little about my comment that you felt the need to tell us all about it and downvote my solution? That's just spiteful.

Comment: Hope you understood my last comment.

Comment: I do, but I'm not so sure about your most recent.

Comment: *"Whenever you want to ask a question, try to ask it in the most silly way"* Is that a guideline that you apply to answers as well?

Comment: Believe me, you can't win out over this.

Comment: No one's trying to "win out" unless you are. I can't even imagine what that might mean in this context. I'm just bemused about your unmannerly response to my criticism and your pompous misuse of the SO voting system.

Comment: All, many apologies for asking a question without giving all the information.

I will create a new, more comprehensive question which hopefully will give the information needed that will allow a suitable answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the files are *fairly* regular (for instance, there are never any spaces around `=` in `Layer=7`, and `CHARTS` is always alone at the beginning of a line) this Perl one-line command will print the filtered output to stdout. I trust you know how to redirect it to a new file?

```
perl -0777 -ne '/Layer=7\b/ or print for split /^(?=CHARTS)/m' myfile
```

#### output

```
CHARTS
 Color=14671839
  Layer=4
  [0] Font=MS SAN SERIF,10,0,F,F,
...other lines...
  [28]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

,

Comment: Ahhh... Non-capturing regex in the split. Me _always_ forget such... ;( Really neat!!

Comment: My existing replacement lines are as follows:

$contents =~ s/\[19\]\= <<<\s+Circle(?s).*?\[28\]\=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,//g;
$contents =~ s/\[19\]\= <<<\s+Draw Line Alarmed(?s).*?\[28\]\=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,//g;

How would I add the one above (perl -0777 -ne '/Layer=7\b/ or print for split /^(?=CHARTS)/m' myfile) in the same format?

Sorry for the low level of expertise here!

Comment: @PaulC: This needs to be a new question. I started by adding it to your existing question (which is where it should have been -- please don't post information in comments as it gets overlooked) but rolled it back as I see it's wrong anyway. Your `[19]` is creating a character class, and will not match `[19]` but instead *either* `1` *or* `9`. You need to escape square brackets if you want to match them literally. Also, please don't use `(?s)` inside a regex pattern unless you want to switch the `/s` modifier on and off inside the pattern. Otherwise it's much better to apply it at the end.

Comment: @PaulC: Also don't escape equals signs. And what are the `<<<`? I don't see anything like that in your data. You'd better show some *real* data in your new question.