# Regex multine replacement perl

Tags: regex, perl, replace, multiline

Posting this question after confusing people yesterday with a slightly sloppy prior version which didn't include sufficient information.

The questions is, I think, a fairly easy one but I am providing a LOT of context to help.

So, I have a file (FILEA.txt), created by an automated system a subset of that file is posted at the bottom of this question and headed as ===DATA===. I am not posting the entire file as it is 36k lines long....unless it is deemed necessary.

The file consists of MANY blocks of text, each of which describe entities (lines/circles/notations etc) on financial charts.

Each block starts with a consistent three lines...

```
CHARTS
  Color=14671839
  Layer=X
```

Where X is a number from 1 through 12. So in the example from the file shown below we have Layer=12.

I already have an automated process which runs daily to reformat the file into multiple formats (FILEB, FILEC, FILED etc) for users that need different formats.

That process consists of 6-7 files. 5-6 of them produce the various formats. These are batch files and one of the examples is below:

```
perl supplement.pl "s/Feed=5,8,F/Feed=3,8,F/g; s/@NQ#/NQ #F/g; s/@ES#/ES #F/g; s/@YM#/YM #F/g; s/QGC#/GC #F/g; s/QSI#/SI #F/g; s/QCL#/CL #F/g; s/QPA#/PA #F/g; s/QHG#/HG #F/g; s/QNG#/NG #F/g; s/@LB#/LBS #F/g; s/@O#/ZO #F/g; s/@RR#/ZR #F/g; s/@S#/ZS #F/g; s/@W#/ZW #F/g; s/@GF#/FC #F/g; s/@LE#/LC #F/g; s/QHO#/HO #F/g; s/@C#/ZC #F/g; s/@DX#/DX #F/g; s/AUDUSD.COMP/AUD A0-FX/g; s/USDCAD.COMP/CAD A0-FX/g; s/USDCHF.COMP/CHF A0-FX/g; s/EURUSD.COMP/EUR A0-FX/g; s/GBPUSD.COMP/GBP A0-FX/g; s/USDJPY.COMP/JPY A0-FX/g; s/NZDUSD.COMP/NZD A0-FX/g; s/@US#/ZB #F/g; s/@TY#/ZN #F/g;" c:/PATHTOFILE/FILEA.txt c:/PATHTOFILE/FILEB.txt
```

It reads in FILEA.txt, performs the conversions and outputs to FILEB.txt

The final file is a supplement.pl, which in addition to the format changes that are contained within each of the batch files, strips two elements from each and every format. The two lines in supplement.pl that strips out alert lines and circles each start with "$contents =~".

I am looking to add a third 'strip' line that strips out each block in its entirety WHERE Layer=7. I figured this would look for Charts/n  Color=14671839/n  Layer=7 all the way through to the next "Charts" and replace the lot with "Charts" meaning the prior block vanishes. I hope this makes sense.

I have tried to be comprehensive here but I am happy to provde additional information if it helps.

===START SUPPLEMENT.PL===

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$sub = shift @ARGV;
$input = shift @ARGV;
$output = shift @ARGV;


open INPUT, "<","$input" or die $!;         
open OUTPUT, ">","$output" or die $!;           

local $/ = undef;
$contents = <INPUT>;

@subs = split('; ', $sub);
foreach (@subs)
{
    @re = split( m/(?<!\\)\//, $_);
    tr/\\//d for @re;

    $contents =~ s/$re[1]/$re[2]/g;
}

$contents =~ s/\[19\]\= <<<\s+Circle(?s).*?\[28\]\=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,//g;
$contents =~ s/\[19\]\= <<<\s+Draw Line Alarmed(?s).*?\[28\]\=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,//g;
===NEED STRIP NEW LINE HERE===

print OUTPUT $contents;

close INPUT;
close OUTPUT;
```

===END SUPPLEMENT.PL===

==START SAMPLE DATA===

```
CHARTS
  Color=14671839
  Layer=12
  [0] Font=MS SAN SERIF,10,0,F,F,
  [1] Show=F,F,F,T,T,F,T,F,F,T,
  [2] Scale=F,F,T,F,F,F,F,F,0,T,F,
  [3] Grid=F,F,F,F,1,
  [4] Paint=F,F,F,0,0,0,
  [5] Bars=1,2000,1970,
  [6] Colors=65793,0,0,8388608,32767,65793,0,0,
  [7] Theme=6,0,255,65280,7566080,0,16777215,0,
  [8] Candles=F,F,F,F,1,F,
  [9] Filter=T,F,F,F,F,0,0
  [10] Type=F,F,F,F,15,44656,
  [11] Spacing=3,49,0,10,4,-7,73,
  [12] Range=56.16,18.72,0.01,0.01
  [13] Volume=0,100,0,0,0,0,
  [14] Refresh=0,0,0,
  [15] Feed=5,1,F,
  [16] Template=
  [17] Symbol=XLP.W
  [18] SubSizes=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,

  [19]= <<<    Note: SPDR Consumer Staples Sector   >>>
  [20]=76,44700,0,0,513,2304,29325,4158,10,59619,29671,10589,21907,2496,29325,4158,10,
  [21]=-2083405824,1,0,8388608,255,16711680,16711680,16711680,16711680,11842740,0,0,0,0,0,0,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,
  [22]=-2083405705,1,1035611788,-1096111445,1151639552,1101497088,1147076608,1435707648,1696464,5525461,1921845696,659518,13,29,182101436,1696464,1696712,1696552,139104368,4830724,1696712,2,1696712,4225200,139104368,1696552,
  [23]=8,0,2,67167744,1150116,0,1150116,67137536,1150828,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,3,1,0,0,0,0,
  [24]=0,71,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,84,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,28,83,80,68,82,32,67,111,110,115,117,109,101,114,32,83,116,97,112,108,101,115,32,83,101,99,116,111,114,
  [25]=255,242,118,160,226,25,0,80,120,35,2,0,0,0,0,71,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,213,15,122,1,240,27,244,118,0,0,0,0,252,36,11,116,152,13,232,115,116,20,35,
  [26]=0,71,1,0,0,236,162,218,10,0,0,0,0,192,73,156,1,177,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,24,198,216,10,28,0,0,0,166,13,232,115,42,0,0,0,16,227,25,0,92,15,167,118,36,
  [27]=163,218,10,252,197,216,10,28,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,224,228,25,0,228,4,0,0,105,15,167,118,110,115,117,109,0,0,0,0,28,0,0,0,0,0,0,64,1,0,0,0,68,227,25,
  [28]=5506571,1696712,139104368,139104368,5506571,1696712,139104368,139104368,1944577216,24776661,0,327,0,0,3366912,1,1435707981,-2147483648,1995709424,327,0,0,0,2298996,0,

  [19]= <<<    Line     h    19.28    58.58   >>>
  [20]=65,44701,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [21]=16711680,16711680,8421376,0,255,255,16711680,16711680,65280,16744447,32767,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [22]=0,0,118.33334,0,118.33334,19.2794,58.58068,58.58068,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [23]=1,0,0,0,1161209,0,1161209,255,1090313,1,2,2,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,
  [24]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [25]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [26]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [27]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [28]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,

  [19]= <<<    Line     i    45.35    84.64   >>>
  [20]=65,44702,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [21]=16711680,16711680,8421376,0,255,255,16711680,16711680,65280,16744447,32767,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [22]=0,0,359.66666,0.33333,359.66666,45.34758,84.64344,84.64344,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [23]=1,0,0,0,1161209,0,1161209,255,1131025,1,2,2,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,
  [24]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [25]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [26]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [27]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [28]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,

CHARTS
  Color=14671839
  Layer=12
  [0] Font=MS SAN SERIF,10,0,F,F,
  [1] Show=F,F,F,T,T,F,T,F,F,T,
  [2] Scale=F,F,T,F,F,F,F,F,0,T,F,
  [3] Grid=F,F,F,F,1,
  [4] Paint=F,F,F,0,0,0,
  [5] Bars=1,2000,1970,
  [6] Colors=65793,0,0,8388608,32767,65793,0,0,
  [7] Theme=6,0,255,65280,7566080,0,16777215,0,
  [8] Candles=F,F,F,F,1,F,
  [9] Filter=T,F,F,F,F,0,0
  [10] Type=F,F,F,F,15,44657,
  [11] Spacing=10,261,0,10,4,-7,73,
  [12] Range=53.46,41.04,0.01,0.01
  [13] Volume=0,100,0,0,0,0,
  [14] Refresh=0,0,0,
  [15] Feed=5,1,F,
  [16] Template=
  [17] Symbol=EWW.W
  [18] SubSizes=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,

  [19]= <<<    Line     p    57.74    31.41   >>>
  [20]=65,47387,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [21]=16711680,16711680,8421376,0,255,255,16711680,16711680,65280,16744447,32767,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [22]=0,0,82.25,0,82.25,57.74,31.41068,31.41068,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [23]=1,0,0,0,1161209,0,1161209,255,1130628,1,2,2,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,
  [24]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [25]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [26]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [27]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [28]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,

  [19]= <<<    Line     q    77.54    51.23   >>>
  [20]=65,47388,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [21]=16711680,16711680,8421376,0,255,255,16711680,16711680,65280,16744447,32767,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [22]=0,0,65.5,0.25,65.5,77.53828,51.22672,51.22672,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [23]=1,0,0,0,1161209,0,1161209,255,1130301,1,2,2,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,
  [24]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [25]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [26]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [27]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [28]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,

  [19]= <<<    Line     r    62.76    36.45   >>>
  [20]=65,47389,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [21]=16711680,16711680,8421376,0,255,255,16711680,16711680,65280,16744447,32767,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [22]=0,0,165.25,0,165.25,62.75862,36.44707,36.44707,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [23]=1,0,0,0,1161209,0,1161209,255,1150130,1,2,2,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,
  [24]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [25]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [26]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [27]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [28]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,

CHARTS
  Color=14671839
  Layer=12
  [0] Font=MS SAN SERIF,10,0,F,F,
  [1] Show=F,F,F,T,T,F,T,F,F,T,
  [2] Scale=F,F,T,F,F,F,F,F,0,T,F,
  [3] Grid=F,F,F,F,1,
  [4] Paint=F,F,F,0,0,0,
  [5] Bars=1,2000,1970,
  [6] Colors=65793,20480,1376384,8388608,32767,65793,0,0,
  [7] Theme=6,0,255,65280,7566080,0,16777215,0,
  [8] Candles=F,F,F,F,1,F,
  [9] Filter=T,F,F,F,F,0,0
  [10] Type=F,F,F,F,15,44658,
  [11] Spacing=3,290,0,10,4,-7,73,
  [12] Range=39.6,7.92,0.62,0.01
  [13] Volume=0,100,0,0,0,0,
  [14] Refresh=0,0,0,
  [15] Feed=5,1,F,
  [16] Template=
  [17] Symbol=XHB.W
  [18] SubSizes=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,

  [19]= <<<    Line     o    19.94    43.15   >>>
  [20]=65,9114,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [21]=16711680,16711680,8421376,0,255,255,16711680,16711680,65280,16744447,32767,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [22]=0,0,27.5,0,27.5,19.94,43.1505,43.1505,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [23]=1,0,0,0,1160101,0,1160101,255,1100423,1,2,2,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,
  [24]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [25]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [26]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [27]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [28]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,

  [19]= <<<    Line     p     7.96    31.18   >>>
  [20]=65,9115,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [21]=16711680,16711680,8421376,0,255,255,16711680,16711680,65280,16744447,32767,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [22]=0,0,-0.25,0.25,-0.25,7.95896,31.18213,31.18213,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [23]=3,0,0,0,1150605,0,1150605,255,1090313,1,2,2,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,
  [24]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [25]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [26]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [27]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [28]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,

  [19]= <<<    Line     q    11.20    34.43   >>>
  [20]=65,9116,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [21]=16711680,16711680,8421376,0,255,255,16711680,16711680,65280,16744447,32767,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [22]=0,0,88.75,0.25,88.75,11.20242,34.42559,34.42559,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [23]=3,0,0,0,1160101,0,1160101,255,1110624,1,2,2,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,
  [24]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [25]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [26]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [27]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [28]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,

  [19]= <<<    Line     r    18.50    41.72   >>>
  [20]=65,9117,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [21]=16711680,16711680,8421376,0,255,255,16711680,16711680,65280,16744447,32767,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [22]=0,0,133,0.5,133,18.5002,41.72338,41.72338,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [23]=3,0,0,0,1160101,0,1160101,255,1120427,1,2,2,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,
  [24]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [25]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [26]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [27]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [28]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,

  [19]= <<<    Note: SPDR Homebuilders ETF   >>>
  [20]=76,44659,0,0,513,63488,25,5552,29674,39301,9851,27405,26412,63420,25,2963,29325,
  [21]=-2083405824,1,0,8388608,255,16711680,16711680,16711680,16711680,11842740,0,0,0,0,0,0,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,
  [22]=-2083405705,1,1056964608,1106597205,1155792896,1090936302,1146437632,0,1,0,0,112,-1,-1,1944577820,1944579083,0,0,0,0,0,1921845696,0,31918584,0,16,
  [23]=
```

==END SAMPLE DATA===

Comment: Honestly, i still dont get what do you want - because: your input data containing too much unnecessary parts, and mainly, because you MISSED to add the WANTED output... :) The [mcve] is a good thing.

Comment: I did detail the required output above. I need to remove the entirety of a block from Charts.... to the next Charts WHERE Layer=7.

I honestly don't know how else to articulate this. Sorry, it is actually a really simple requirement but I seem not to be able to communicate it.

Comment: Yesterday I already answered your question. Replace the `===NEED STRIP NEW LINE HERE===` with the `$contents = join 'CHARTS', grep { !/Layer\s*=\s*7\b/ } split /\bCHARTS\b/, $contents;` (from the [yesterday's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43168103/632407) and you're done. You also could use any other answer too, like `$contents =  join '', grep { !/Layer\s*=\s*7\b/ } split /^(?=CHARTS)/m, $contents`. Both solves the problem, and here isn't any need asking again the same question.

Comment: Did you even tried any of the yesterday's answers about removing the charts block with `Layer=7`?

Comment: @jm666 I tried both suggestions above but the output file is created but empty. Neither creates any errors and runs but produces zero output.

Comment: @PaulC my last try to help you. Added an answer. Using **exactly** your code (and your run command) and your data, just added the one line. It produces output. If for you not, you either: using different script, or ... nah. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, from your question:

> I am looking to add a third 'strip' line that strips out each block in
>   its entirety **WHERE Layer=7**.

Did you noticed, that in your sample data isn't any section containing `Layer=7`?

Now the solution:

**Excetly your code**, with the added line from the comments (e.g. from the answers to [your previous same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43167768/632407).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$sub = shift @ARGV;
$input = shift @ARGV;
$output = shift @ARGV;


open INPUT, "<","$input" or die $!;         
open OUTPUT, ">","$output" or die $!;           

local $/ = undef;
$contents = <INPUT>;

@subs = split('; ', $sub);
foreach (@subs)
{
    @re = split( m/(?<!\\)\//, $_);
    tr/\\//d for @re;

    $contents =~ s/$re[1]/$re[2]/g;
}

$contents =~ s/\[19\]\= <<<\s+Circle(?s).*?\[28\]\=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,//g;
$contents =~ s/\[19\]\= <<<\s+Draw Line Alarmed(?s).*?\[28\]\=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,//g;

#this is the added line
$contents = join '', grep { !/Layer\s*=\s*7\b/ } split /^(?=CHARTS)/m, $contents;
#or this works too
#$contents = join 'CHARTS', grep { !/Layer\s*=\s*7\b/ } split /\bCHARTS\b/, $contents;

print OUTPUT $contents;

close INPUT;
close OUTPUT;
```

The above:

- Is tested against **your** data.
- It produces output.
- And, if you will have in the input data some `CHARTS section` containing `Layer=7` it will be removed.

Comment: thanks a million for your support. It works A OK. I see now that my issue was a missing print OUTPUT line.

Sorry for being so slow, this is not my forte and I appreciate your patience.

Comment: @PaulC yw and enjoy. :) You also could read: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I just wanted to follow up with @jm666 on this. I tried to vote on this solution when you posted it but apparently my reputation was insufficient (<15) and I wasn't allowed to vote. I was though able to select it as the answer. I came back today to ask a follow up question and see that my reputation is mysteriously now 16 so I am voting. Sorry if it seemed I vanished without giving you props for the work you put into the solution and thanks once again.