# Need modification to existing multiline Perl replacement code

Tags: perl, text

I had [a recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43185670/regex-multine-replacement-perl/43204651?noredirect=1#comment73483202_43204651) earlier this month which was solved by @jm666 which involved multi line text replacement.

I have an issue in that, although this works perfectly as requested, it results in the removal of some text at the very end of the text file which I need to retain.

The line added to my process file which strips the blocks of text is below:

```
$contents = join '', grep { !/Layer\s*=\s*7\b/ } split /^(?=CHARTS)/m, $contents;
```

The data below shows what is being stripped. Each block of text commences with `CHARTS` and ends with `[28]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,`

There is then a blank line and we are on to the next block, which again commences with `CHARTS`.

The line shown at the start of the question correctly strips each entire block (from start to finish) where `Layer=7`, which is in the 4th line of each block.

The very last block in the file is then followed by some information which formats things. That information commences with `STACK`. Below the sample code below I show that `STACK` info.

I have posted [a 2 min video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EQSWXuMONLc) which describes the issue in detail

```
CHARTS
  Position=574,1988,1013,2652,-1,-1
  Color=14671839
  Layer=7
  [0] Font=MS SAN SERIF,10,0,F,F,
  [1] Show=F,F,F,T,T,F,T,F,F,T,
  [2] Scale=F,F,T,F,F,F,F,F,0,T,F,
  [3] Grid=F,F,F,F,1,
  [4] Paint=F,F,F,0,0,0,
  [5] Bars=1,2000,1970,
  [6] Colors=65793,0,0,8388608,32767,65793,0,0,
  [7] Theme=6,0,255,65280,7566080,0,16777215,0,
  [8] Candles=F,F,F,F,1,F,
  [9] Filter=T,F,F,F,F,0,0
  [10] Type=F,F,F,F,15,5083,
  [11] Spacing=5,236,0,10,4,-7,73,
  [12] Range=227.8,107.2,2.05,0.01
  [13] Volume=0,100,0,0,0,0,
  [14] Refresh=0,0,0,
  [15] Feed=5,5,F,
  [16] Template=
  [17] Symbol=@OJ#.W
  [18] SubSizes=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,

  [19]= <<<    Andrews Pitchfork  1   >>>
  [20]=61,5085,0,1,192,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [21]=16711935,16711935,16711935,255,16711935,255,16711935,16711935,65793,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [22]=2,7,0,0,0,64.58475,226.99976,97.1011,35,2,0,0,25,38.2,50,61.8,75,100,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [23]=146,0,0,2,1120518,0,1120127,255,1090220,1,3,3,1,1,4,1,1,3,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,
  [24]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [25]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [26]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [27]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [28]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,

  [19]= <<<    c:\XXXXX\Alerts\AUD.wav   103.47   672.59   >>>
  [20]=65,5088,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [21]=65280,65280,8421376,0,255,255,16711680,16711680,65280,16744447,32767,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [22]=0,0,0,0,2730.6001,103.47184,672.59155,103.47184,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [23]=3,0,0,0,1120914,0,1170120,255,1120914,1,5,5,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,
  [24]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,26,99,58,92,69,110,115,105,103,110,49,
  [25]=48,92,65,108,101,114,116,115,92,65,85,68,46,119,97,118,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [26]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [27]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [28]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,

  [19]= <<<    Line     t   160.65   729.77   >>>
  [20]=65,5089,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [21]=16711935,16711680,8421376,0,255,255,16711680,16711680,65280,16744447,32767,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [22]=0,0,0,0,2892.6001,160.65494,729.77466,160.65494,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [23]=1,0,0,0,1151023,0,1170120,255,1151023,1,2,2,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,
  [24]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [25]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [26]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [27]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [28]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,

CHARTS
  Position=-462,3460,-23,4124,-1,-1
  Color=14671839
  Layer=1
  [0] Font=MS SAN SERIF,10,0,F,F,
  [1] Show=F,F,F,T,T,F,T,F,F,T,
  [2] Scale=F,F,T,F,F,F,F,F,0,T,F,
  [3] Grid=F,F,F,F,1,
  [4] Paint=F,F,F,0,0,0,
  [5] Bars=1,2000,1970,
  [6] Colors=65793,0,0,8388608,32767,65793,0,0,
  [7] Theme=6,0,255,65280,7566080,0,16777215,0,
  [8] Candles=F,F,F,F,1,F,
  [9] Filter=T,F,F,F,F,0,0
  [10] Type=F,F,F,F,15,43286,
  [11] Spacing=5,183,0,10,4,-7,73,
  [12] Range=148.5,89.1,0.01,0.01
  [13] Volume=0,100,0,0,0,0,
  [14] Refresh=0,0,0,
  [15] Feed=5,2,F,
  [16] Template=
  [17] Symbol=SVXY.D
  [18] SubSizes=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,

  [19]= <<<    Circle   >>>
  [20]=62,43296,0,0,576,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [21]=13959167,16711680,65280,255,255,5242880,16744192,12900,255,5242880,16727871,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [22]=2,7,0,0,-0.28571,134.64,135.71358,134.62071,15,0,0,0,25,38.2,50,61.8,75,100,150,161.8,200,0,0,0,0,0,
  [23]=130,2,0,2,1170222,1,1170222,1,1170215,0,2,0,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,
  [24]=176,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,177,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,250,25,0,117,4,119,0,216,250,25,
  [25]=0,64,202,15,5,4,182,73,0,168,233,105,179,2,0,0,0,117,4,119,0,176,120,64,0,64,202,15,5,32,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [26]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [27]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [28]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,

  [19]= <<<    Circle   >>>
  [20]=62,43297,0,0,576,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [21]=13959167,16711680,65280,255,255,5242880,16744192,12900,255,5242880,16727871,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [22]=2,7,1.85714,-0.14286,1.57143,145.22144,146.31429,145.22144,15,0,0,0,25,38.2,50,61.8,75,100,150,161.8,200,0,0,0,0,0,
  [23]=130,2,0,2,1170323,1,1170323,1,1170321,0,2,0,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,
  [24]=176,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,177,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,250,25,0,117,4,119,0,216,250,25,
  [25]=0,64,202,15,5,4,182,73,0,168,233,105,179,2,0,0,0,117,4,119,0,176,120,64,0,64,202,15,5,32,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [26]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [27]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [28]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,

  [19]= <<<    Circle   >>>
  [20]=62,44362,0,0,576,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [21]=13959167,16711680,65280,255,255,5242880,16744192,12900,255,5242880,16727871,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [22]=2,7,0.09091,0,0.09091,63.96,63.93712,63.93712,15,0,0,0,25,38.2,50,61.8,75,100,150,161.8,200,0,0,0,0,0,
  [23]=130,2,0,2,1161108,1,1161108,1,1161104,0,2,0,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,
  [24]=176,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,177,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,250,25,0,123,2,159,3,216,250,25,
  [25]=0,64,202,15,5,4,182,73,0,168,233,105,179,2,0,0,0,123,2,159,3,176,120,64,0,64,202,15,5,32,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [26]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [27]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  [28]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
```

So, here below is the problem area. The first two lines below are the final two lines of the last block of `CHARTS` data in the file. As you can see, it is then followed by many smaller blocks which commence with `STACK`.

This question is simply looking for a modification to the line of code at the start of the question, replicated once more below, to not strip out the `STACK` blocks. Using the current solution it does remove all the `Layer=7` blocks but it also removes all of the `STACK` blocks at the end of the file. This is despite the final block of text prior to the `STACK` blocks being `Layer=1`, not `Layer=7`.

```
$contents = join '', grep { !/Layer\s*=\s*7\b/ } split /^(?=CHARTS)/m, $contents;
```

[27]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
      [28]=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,

```
STACK
  Position=399,390,888,1211,0,1048
  Color=-16777201
  Layer=6
  ID=56729,56730,56731,56732,56733,56734,56735,
  [1] Name=
  [2] Index=1,
  [3] Pinned=F,
  [4] Font=8,-16777208,F,MS SANS SERIF
  Window=Minimized

STACK
  Position=399,684,888,1348,0,1048
  Color=-16777201
  Layer=1
  ID=28487,9939,
  [1] Name=
  [2] Index=0,
  [3] Pinned=F,
  [4] Font=8,-16777208,F,MS SANS SERIF
  Window=Minimized

STACK
```

Comment: I think the reason that it removes the final part is that one of the final STACK blocks also contain `Layer=7`

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a forum; it is more like a wiki which contains answers to programming issues. As such, a question's primary worth is in its accessibility and meaning to the many other people who may find the page when searching for a resolution to their own problems. So please don't leave your question derelict and useless once you have your answer. Putting the bulk of your message into a video is highly unusual, but to delete that video as soon as you get a solution is unforgiveable. Please edit your question to include a transcription of the video with other people in mind.

Comment: Please don't use capital letters for emphasis. We are not stupid. Italics are much more pleasant to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided `STACK` blocks does only occur at the end of the file, you can try to also split out the `STACK` blocks:

```
$contents = join '', grep { /^STACK/ || !/Layer\s*=\s*7\b/ } split /^(?=CHARTS|STACK)/m, $contents;
```